# Connect to bucket name that named not 'default'

Tags: couchbase, bucket

I have a Couchbase server and a .Net client. When I named the bucket "default" every thing run ok but when I create a bucket with another name like 'cashdb' my client got error "Null Pointer Exception".

I really don't know if you want to have 3 bucket on a server with difference names , what can you do?

Comment: can you add more context for the Exception, the code you run and the version of the SDK you use? in .Net 2.0 SDK, one can use the `OpenBucket(BucketName, BucketPassword)` method on `Cluster` to open a bucket other than the default one, I guess it's what you want to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple buckets (or even a single bucket that's not named 'default'), you have to explicitly specify which one you want to open when creating the connection.

In the 1.x SDK it's:

```
var config = new CouchbaseClientConfiguration();
config.Bucket = "mybucket"
config.BucketPassword = "12345";
var connection = new CouchbaseClient(config);
```

In the 2.x SDK it's slightly longer, so take a look here: http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dotnet-2.0/configuring-the-client.html

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer the part about the .Net drive, but I can address the multiple bucket questions.

You can have multiple buckets, but know why you are doing it. A logical organization is not necessarily a great reason, IMO. More buckets means more resources being used. I can give you a great example of a when you would split data into separate buckets, views. If you have views that only look at a subset of the data you have and will never ever look at the other parts of the data, then it might make sense to split it out. Say you have some JSON docs that are 30% of your data and a bunch of key value pairs that are 70% of your data. More than likely, you would only ever do views on the JSON docs and if there are enough of those docs and in large enough sizes, it can provide much faster view creation, maintenance, cluster rebalances, etc.

Another reason is if you have multiple applications accessing the same cluster. That is a good reason too.

Anyhow, it is fine to have multiple buckets, just read up on and understand the implications and do it strategically.